# Cómo puedo obtener los N últimos valores de una lista

Tags: c#

quisiera saber como puedo seleccionar el ultimo valor de una lista, hice un `foreach` pero en este caso me selecciona todos los datos pero quisiera saber como puedo hacer para que me seleccione los últimos cuatro valores

este es el código del foreach:

```
 public List<PCharts> Data { get; set; }

        public ViewModelCharts(Dashboard_Response data)
        {
            Data = new List<PCharts>();



            foreach (var _data in data.data)
            {
                Data.Add(new PCharts() {
                    Name = string.Format("{0}", _data.id), Height = _data.ejex
                });

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Puedes utilizar LINQ seleccionando los elementos con el método `Skip` y creando los objetos en el `Select`:

```
var Data = data.data.Skip(Math.Max(0, data.data.Count - 4))
        .Select(x=> new PCharts {Name=$"{x.id}", Height = x.ejex })
        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 3):

Usando la respuesta siguiente: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3453301/4955425, se puede usar `.Skip(n)` y `.Count()` con LINQ para obtener los últimos 4 valores:

```
foreach (var _data in data.data
    .Skip(Math.Max(0, data.data.Count() - 4)))
{
    // ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Otra opción sería usar los metodos `Reverse` y `Take`:

```
var Data=data.data.Reverse().Take(4).ToList().Reverse();
```

Comment: @sstan Si,tienes razón, si quieres conservar el orden de esos elementos hace falta otro `Reverse`. Editado